# Next Build Error - Error occurred prerendering page / TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-dom-server

I'm trying to update a 2 year old project, and I've been having so much trouble after updating the dependencies

Right now after running 'next build', I keeps seeing:

*Error occurred prerendering page "/japan-vlogs". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')*

for every page in my project

How do I even begin to debug this? The docs site has 5 different options and none of which say anything about the react dom server browser or use memo

screenshots hosted here:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44171#discussion-4678699

Answer (score 0):

The error message `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')"` indicates that you are trying to access a property of an object that is null or undefined. This can occur if you are trying to access a property of an object that has not been initialized, or if you are trying to access a property of an object that has been set to null.

From the Screenshot you provided it indicates that in "JapanVlog" you are trying to use ternary operator or short circuit,

Try this:

1. Change `<Japan/> : null` to `<Japan/>`. if you wanna dynamically display  Component try useState Hooks instead

if that doesn't work

2. Search every function using useMemo() Hooks
3. Check is any of those function returns `null`

Hope that works

Comment: 1) removing the : null doesn't help 2) no functions use useMemo(), the only times that shows up in the code is in the node modules for react dom server 3) nothing returns null. It's all just static web pages - no logic needed

Comment: it might be a conflict for some package, try update latest version of it, and can you provide some other details

Comment: This looks like a ChatGPT answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. using `yarn build` instead of `next build` seems to fix it for now. [checkout this issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/43942)